# Prevent variable substitution when writing string to file with cat <<EOL

Tags: bash, shell, heredoc

I'd like to write a string to a file in a bash script, but don't know how prevent variables from being expanded. An example script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat >./foo.bar <<EOL
t=$(ping 8.8.8.8)
EOL
```

Produces the output:

```
t=
Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=57
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=57
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=57
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=57

Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 16ms, Maximum = 17ms, Average = 16ms
```

So it seems `$(ping 8.8.8.8)` is being executed and the output is being written to the file. How do I write the literal string provided without expanding anything?

Comment: I think the reason I didn't find the linked question was because I didn't know what I was doing was called a 'here-document'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
cat >./foo.bar <<'EOL'
t=$(ping 8.8.8.8)
EOL
```

Quoting [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents):

> `[n]<<[-]word`
>
> If any part of `word` is quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote
>   removal on `word`, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded.

Comment: In short, the quotes enclosing EOL makes the magic.